# Calling python scripts and functions through other scripts [in raspian]

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, method-call

I'm running into a problem on my Raspberry Pi 4 (running Raspbian) where: when I run a Python script through a terminal that invokes a subsequent Python script upon the successful run, returns the error "NameError: function is not defined"

example (not the actual code)

#script1.py

```
def do_a_thing1():
   print("Hello World")

exec(open("script2.py").read())
```

#script2.py

```
def do_a_thing2():
   e = c ** 2
   return e

def do_a_thing3():
   x = do_a_thing2
   x = m * x
   return x
```

trying to come up with a simple example on the fly. but realistically, I have 5 steps in my process, and each step has a validation check to validate its own data, once checked and the validation has passed, an if statement invokes the consecutive step. I've read up the potential import & from solutions, but I'm unsure if the import needs to reside in the main function or the consecutive functions. any help would be appreciated on this topic. thank you!

print(x)

Comment: Take a look at subprocess.Popen() as a better way to run another script. It can return a tuple of an output from the called script and any error condition. `(out, err) = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()` where mycmd is your os-level command.

Comment: You can also import the other script and use it as a library

Comment: Thank you @BalooRM ! this seemed to work as I used the subprocess.run() feature after reading up on some documentation that suited my needs best. I'm working on automation, so it worked during a forced test but will have to wait until next week Friday for the script to be invoked to see the real results. thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, @Abe M. I use `subprocess.Popen()` for automation with tests on the `err` for reporting and input to resolving errors. Feel free to write up an answer to your question.